# Bevel path tapering with none selected

Tags: bezier-curves, bevel

I am trying to trace over and copy a pattern with a bezier poly curve with a square plane set to the profile in order to achieve a 3d representation.

[image]

You can see the pattern here, however when I apply the profile I find certain segments have no thickness and some segments taper.
[image]

Is there a way to modify the bezier poly line to properly achieve what I want? I'm at a loss for whats causing this behaviour. Or is there another, simpler way to get the same result?
Thanks!

Comment: maybe you need to switch from 3D to 2D in the Object Data > Shape? Could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blender does not allow its curves to branch.. maybe a better way would be something along the lines of starting with a mesh grid, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> dissolving unwanted vertices, and <kbd>K</kbd> cutting in your occasional diagonals? (Top Left, below)..

[image]

- Then (Top Right) <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> select vertices with 2 connecting edges, and dissolve those, too. (Here, I've deselected the plane's corners before dissolving, for tidiness)...
- ..making way for a clean Bevel, or *Bevel* modifier, on all edges, with 1 segment, and no 'Limit' method, and no 'Clamp Overlap'..
- ... resulting bevel-faces can be selected by area (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> again), and <kbd>E</kbd> extruded.

If you need to isolate and solidify the paths, you can :

- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> Select > Coplanar the top faces of  the extrusion
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> invert the selection, and delete those other faces..
- .. and give the paths a Solidify modifier.

[image]

(2 copies shown for illustration)

Comment: Thank you ill give this a shot!

Comment: @goldencanine Thanks!  I've edited, in case you need to fill the bottom of your extrusion.

Comment: I'm not sure how you achieved the beveled paths in the lower left picture. Even after dissolving vertices with two segments and selecting none for limit method all I achieve are fractal patterns after beveling :(

Comment: Hi, @goldencanine .. If you have a clean toplogy  (no duplicate verts, or anything?) as in the top-right, a simple  Ctrl-B bevel on all edges _should_ do it. If you're sure about that, maybe you could share an example of your problem on https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @goldencanine Ahh! Maybe its a 'Clamp Overlap' in the bevel. That should be unchecked. The bevel should be small enough not to use it. (Personally, I always uncheck 'Clamp Overlap'.)

Comment: Without clamp overlay and using ctrl B i got it to work! Thanks for following up on this. So sorry to ask you something else, but how do I mirror in Z to fill out the bottom? Forgive my poor knowledge!

Comment: @goldencanine I've changed my mind.. for some reason I didn't think _Solidify_ would do the job, but it's fine, and simpler than mirroring. See Edit. (Actually, this way, you don't need the extrusion at all. Just delete the unbevelled faces)